# Inspect element in firefox like in safari?

Tags: html, javascript, web

Here is a screenshot from the d3.js [tutorial webpage:](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/binding-data)

[image]

This way of inspection in safari is quite cool, is there a way to do this in firefox?

---

Let me make things clearer, I have a page with the following source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>D3 Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.v3.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
var dataset = [ 5, 10, 15, 20, 25 ];
d3.select("body").selectAll("p")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("p")
.text(function(d) {
    return "I can count up to " + d;
});
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

And it seems in safari, for each

element, it displays a property called `__data__`, which is what the d3.js script feeds into them.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not inspecting HTML. You're viewing the results of a JavaScript function call.

Firefox's console does a similar thing:

[image: Screenshot]

Note that smc's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/751427/117590) is the *correct* way to view HTML/the DOM.

Also, I'm still running one version older; the newer version looks even better (and is smart enough to link to the inspector, the place you *should* be inspecting the DOM).

Comment: you see the small triangle at the left side? it's not expandable in firefox, while it is in safari.

Comment: I have added another screenshot into the question.

Comment: @qed You click on the underlined part to get it on the *right hand side*. It's not an exact clone, and it's not designed to be. It performs *the same function*. Also, FF Nightly (and possibly Beta/Aurora/29) will show some more detail on the left, but that's not the point. Your second screenshot shows nothing special: if a `__data__` member exists, FF will show it. My example doesn't, because I can't be bothered testing your special case when the general works. Your `d3` script has *nothing* to do with how the developer console works; it'll work the same regardless of the object you inspect.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can simply right click and then select "Inspect Element (Q)"

[image]

Then you will get a very similar interface:

[image]

Comment: It's different, the screenshot shows inspection in the console, and it also show some 'hidden' attributes like __proto__ and __data__

Answer (score 1):

That being said, there are numerous add-on/Extensions for Firefox which resemble what you are asking.
A popular add-on is: FireBug which is part of the Web Developer. Which will breakdown and show in "real-time" which piece of html/javascript/css is being displayed. One of many suggestions...

Edit: There is the console based on the Web Developer. I stand corrected. Firebug extends the console functionality. Additional information on firebug is to graphically show where elements reside inside the page structure and how they interact. Inspect HTML and modify style and layout in real-time, accurately analyze network usage and performance, inspect and edit HTML code, visualize CSS metrics, debug and profile javascript, logging for javascript, and the features go on.

Comment: Firefox has had a built-in developer console for many months. Actually, I'm pretty sure it's years now. This answer is wrong.

Comment: Despite the part of Firefox not having a built-in developer console (which is wrong), it would be preferable if you could point out if FireBug does what the OP wants. It certainly extends the built-in developer's tools, but to what extent?

Comment: Feels like I`m in one those scientific journals... Very well, I don`t actually answer questions on a regular basis.

Comment: @BlizzardsGambit Eh, we value correctness. Don't feel discouraged; just correct it, learn new things and move on. I apologise if I was a bit blunt in my original comment. Incidentally, most/all Firebug features are now part of the standard dev console, and the standard dev console tends to run faster - it's difficult to recommend Firebug nowadays.